# Apache HTTP : How to set custom ContentType

Tags: java, http, mime-types, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using the apache http client to upload a file as

```
public void whenSendMultipartRequestUsingHttpClient_thenCorrect() 
  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addTextBody("ads", "John");
    builder.addTextBody("qwe", "pass");
    builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("test.txt"),
      ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file.ext");

    HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
    httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(200));
    client.close();
}
```

the problem is that the server side needs the `ContentType` of the file to be `application/myCustomTag`

However, this is not a value in the `ContentType` interface. Is there any way for me to provide a custom string as `ContentType`?

**EDIT**

I tried to recreate the request as seen on the browser

with my request headers as

```
[X-head1: {someJson}, Accept: application/json, X-head2: someVal, X-head3: otherVal, Content-Type: application/json]
```

and the payload

```
[Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file.ext"; filename="test.txt", Content-Type: application/octet-stream, Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary]
```

the key difference that i can see is that in the payload i see the following in the browser

`Content-Type: application/myCustomTag`

which is not an HTTP standard `Content-Type` so i cannot set it as such

Comment: Did you try with *ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA*?

Comment: What about `httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","'application/myCustomTag");`

Comment: thanks, ii tried that but i still get 500 from the server

Comment: @tsolakp Your comment was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setHeader on your HttpPost ?
[API here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html#setHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Alternative:

ContentType.create("application/myCustomTag")

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternative. (to be used with addBinaryBody)